# Why does cout give me the wrong integer?

Tags: c++

When I build and run this code in Eclipse CDT, I expect it to print `1`. It prints `-1992206527` instead. Why is this?

Here's my code.

## A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A {
private:
    int a;
public:
    A();
    ~A();

    void printNum();
};

#endif
```

## A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

A::A() :
    a(1)
{

}

A::~A(){}

void A::printNum(){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

## B.h

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

class A;

class B {
private:
    A*  obj;
public:
    B();
    ~B();

    int run();
};

#endif
```

## B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

B::B() {}

B::~B() {}

int B::run(){
    obj->printNum();
    return 0;
}
```

## main.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    B b;
    return b.run();
}
```

Comment: You haven't initilized `B::obj`.

Comment: ... and why would you want it to be a pointer?

Comment: @juanchopanza How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it print 1, you must initialize B::obj. Below is a B.cpp with obj being properly initialized/ deallocated.

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

B::B() : obj(new A) {}

B::~B() { delete obj;}

int B::run(){
    obj->printNum();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could make obj  be an object type A(i.e declare obj as `A obj;`), instead of making it a pointer to an object of type A. This would necessitate including  `A.h`in `B.h`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll stick with including `A.h` in `B.h` for simplicity